# Joint distribution and the probability of event X>Y for discrete random variables X,Y

Tags: probability

In a fourth year statistics course there are 10 actuarial science students, 9 statistics students and 6 math business students. Five students are selected at random without replacement. Let X be the number of actuarial students selected and let Y be the number of statistics students selected.

Find
(a) the joint of X and Y
(b) the marginal p.f. of X
(c) the marginal p.f. of Y
(d) P(X>Y)

#### Progress

I know to find (a), (b) and (c) but I don't have any ideas for (d)

The joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$ that I found is
$$
P(x,y) =  \binom{10}{x} \binom{9}{y} \binom{6}{5-x-y} \bigg/ \binom{25}{5} 
$$

Comment: Your answer for (a) could be useful in (d). What did you get in (a)?

Comment: (10Cx)(9Cy)(6C5-x-y)/(25C5)

Answer (score 1):

Use the $P(x,y)$ you computed.  Let $n = x-y-1$; the condition $(X>Y)$ implies that $n \geq 0$.  Substitute for $y$ with $y = x-n-1$ the resulting probability is then
$$
\frac{1}{\binom{25}{5}} \sum_x \sum_{n\geq 0} \binom{10}{x}\binom{9}{x-n-1}\binom{6}{2x-n}
$$
Although this double sum looks ugly, in fact only $9$ non-zero terms appear. If my arithmetic is right, the answer comes out to 
$$\frac{23127}{53130} \approx 43.5\%$$
Note that even though $X$ has a larger expectation than $Y$, the probability that $X>Y$ is less than $\frac{1}{2}$.  This is because there is a significant chance that $X=Y$, so the chance that $Y>X$ is even less than that $43.5\%$.

Comment: How can i simplify the double sum? I should substitute N=0,1,2,...,9 and X=0,1,...,10?